# How ca I upload a file to become a class in my eclipse projet

Tags: eclipse, class

I have a would like to import class to my projet in eclipse. The class are in a folder and I don't know how to import them to a class. thanks

Comment: Go search it up online. I got 997,000 results by searching it up.

Comment: I cann't find it how to put in the class can you show me a link that explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how to import a class to your project in eclipse. 
link: 
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-55.htm

I got this from the eclipse website. All this stuff is on the web.